# Google Maps: show opened infoboxes/popups

Tags: google-maps

I want some basic information for cities to be available on a Google map. The idea is that when people open the map, they see the information already opened, instead of having to click on every marker. Yet I can not figure out if this is something that is possible. I've gone through all samples and have not seen this being employed. Does such an option exist? I attach a visual sample of my intentions.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can you iterate through all of your Marker objects and call setVisible(true) ?  That's what I'd try (I'm only familiar with V3 of the API) e.g.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position:map.getCenter()});
 marker.setVisible(true);
```

The above example shows how to do this for a single Marker, but you can do this to all Markers (maybe hold them in a data structure and iterate through them)

Answer (score 1):

Simply iterate through your marker data on initialization and create info windows based on marker locations.

```
<html>
    <head>

        <script type="text/javascript" src= "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script>
            var map;
            //this json contains your raw data as well as space to store created marker and infowindow objects 
            info = [{
                "content": "content 1",
                "coords":[-34.397, 150.644],
                "marker":null,
                "infowindow": null
            },{
                "content": "content 2",
                "coords":[-34.597, 150.644],
                "marker":null,
                "infowindow": null
            }]

            function initialize() {

                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 8,
                    center: latlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                }
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

                for(i=0; i<info.length; i++) {
                    //create markers
                    pos = new google.maps.LatLng(info[i].coords[0],info[i].coords[1])

                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: pos,
                        map: map
                    });
                    //store the marker object for later if you want, useful if you want to keep track of your objects or dynamically alter your objects
                    info[i].marker = marker
                    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: info[i].content
                    });
                    //store info window object for later if you want, useful if you want to keep track of your objects or dynamically alter your objects
                    info[i].infowindow = infowindow;

                    infowindow.open(map,marker);
                }

            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 320px; height: 480px;">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```